# Nixos install results in error during boot of "Timed out waiting for device /dev/dis/by-uuid/... to appear" with external NVME drive via USB

Tags: boot, usb-drive, nixos, initrd, nvme

I have an issue when using an external NVME drive, grub successfully boots but once entering the entry `default configuration` (nixos generation) it gives me the below error:

> "Timed out waiting for device /dev/dis/by-uuid/... to appear"

I've double checked the UUID of the `/` partiton and it correctly matches what is in `/etc/fstab` and `hardware-configuration.nix` (which got generated with `nixos-generate-config`). In the grub recovery console if I do a `ls -l` I can see the partition with the correct UUID as well.

I've also added `"nvme"` to `boot.initrd.availableKernelModules`.

I'm able to `nixos-enter` the system via an external "live usb" with no issue.

I suspect I need an additional initrd kernel module to be able to boot this, but I'm not sure which one?

I've tried:

1. Adding these modules (got these from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromUSB):

```
usbcore
sd_mod
ehci_hcd
uhci_hcd
ohci_hcd
usb_storage
scsi_mod
```

which still results in the same error.

2. Copying the partition to the internal drive (as opposed to the external NVME drive which still results in the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, and what I ended up doing was, with a different Linux installation freshly booted, to compare the output of `lsmod` before and after plugging the USB device in.

What I needed in the end was:

```
boot.initrd.availableKernelModules = [ "uas" "usbcore" "usb_storage" ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure my issue was caused by doing `nixos-rebuild build` instead of `nixos-rebuild boot`. The first command does not create a generation or set it to boot by default.

I likely just needed the additional `nvme` module.